# How to make random dots in different sizes and spaces between the dots in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-scripting, plugin

I am trying to make something similar to this?

Obviously it's possible to make it manually piece by piece, but I am looking for some kind of automated feature in Illustrator to achieve this?

Is this possible?

Thanks man in advance!

[image: space image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Colliderscribe is a great option. Another method of doing it is through the "transform each" feature.

1. Make several copies of the object you want to create a background of. Select them all.
2. Select Object>Transform>Transform Each
3. Type a number of pixels to move the objects horizontally and vertically
4. Type a percentage to scale the objects
5. Tick the "random" option

The results will not be as good as Colliderscribe, but it works.

Answer (score 4):

There is a plugin called **ColliderScribe** of Astute Graphics which is the direct answer of your question. Its a paid plugin but you can download its trial version which is for 14-15 days and use it. you can use the **Space Fill Feature** to achieve your goal.

[image]

You can google for its functionality and tutorial. There are lots of tutorial on this.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the tool that would suit you best for this effect is a scatter brush. You can learn more about the scatter brush here:
http://abduzeedo.com/illustrator-quick-tips-2-scatter-brushes

Comment: would be better if you could describe the answer here instead of just linking; if the link dies your answer will be less valuable.

Answer (score 2):

In Illustrator you can try this way:

1. Create small white circle
2. Make this circle a symbol (just drag it to symbol panel)
3. Spray this symbol everywhere you need with symbol sprayer tool
4. Change sizes of some of this symbols (circles) with  symbol sizer
   tool
5. Change colors of some symbols with symbol stainer tool

Answer (score 1):

i fake particles making a scatter brush, then i apply it to a line whitout fill around the area i want to fill with the particles.
i find this way the easier, sorry for my english.